# How To Update DB Using Code First.Net Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first

Teaching myself .Net Core web stuff.

I have a model and I have successfully created my DB.

Now, I am adding a new Field to my model/class. I want to preserve existing data in this table so do not want to recreate the DB/Table.  How can I update the DB/Table>

I have tried using 'Update-Database' in the Package Manage Console but got an error telling my table already exists. Which I know it does.  But I am updating not creating.

This is my model:

```
public class Subscription
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long SubscriptionId { get; set; }
    public string SubscriptionRef { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Salt { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public bool Disabled { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOE { get; set; }
}
```

This is my DBInitalizer

```
public class DbInitializer
{
    public static void Initialize(WorkerContext context)
    {
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Which is called by my startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddDbContext<WorkerContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

This is my DB context:

```
public class WorkerContext : DbContext
{
    public WorkerContext(DbContextOptions<WorkerContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Models.Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }
}
```

So now I add a new field to my Subscription Table/Model:

```
public string Test { get; set; }
```

I rerun the project (i also type in Update-Database) and no new field is created...

How do I update/edit/modify/delete tables and fields using code 1st techniques?

Thanks

Comment: You need to further explore how [EF Core Migrations works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations).

Comment: Hi, thanks for that link. Good of you

Comment: @FedericoDipuma I would have deleted this question as it now seems obvious but some one has kindly supplied the answer so wrong to do so.

Comment: please write you errors here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use:

```
dotnet ef migrations add "MigrationName" -c ContextName
dotnet ef database update -c ContextName
```

and to remove migration:

```
dotnet ef migrations remove
```

this will remove latest migration

Comment: The first line should be `dotnet ef migrations add "MigrationName" -c "ContextName"`